# WordPress iframe content now showing

Tags: wordpress, iframe

I am trying to show some WP content but only the static text is showing. No WP content is appearing at all.
It does appear that no WP scripts are being loaded looking at the Dev Tools source code?

Any help as to what I have missed is most appreciated.

Here is my call within page.php:

```
<iframe src="http://www.xxxxxx.com/wp-content/themes/themename/iframe-gview.php" width="100%" height="500" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
```

My php template code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Applications</title>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.xxxxxx.com/wp-content/themes/themename/assets/css/style.css">

    Static Content

    <?php
        echo do_shortcode('[gravityview id="1234"]');
    ?>

<?php wp_footer(); ?>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the error in iframe?

Comment: Updated my explanation above @vel

Comment: Are you accessing this url `http://www.xxxxxx.com/wp-content/themes/themename/iframe-gview.php` from any other site

Comment: It's a WP Multisite so yes

Comment: Did you check the shortcode is working fine?

Comment: Yes, shortcode is working fine. I think the issue is that no WP scripts or styles are being loaded into the <head> of the iframe. Even though I have included wp_head(); ?

Comment: yes. if you are accesing template url directly wordpress does not consider as template.

Comment: ahh... So how would I get around this? Create and actual Page Template and assign it to the page? Is that the only way?

Comment: yes. or you should include `require_once('../../../wp-load.php');` in your file

Comment: Thanks that worked!

Comment: glad to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @vel mentioned above, this solved my problem:

```
<?php require_once('../../../wp-load.php'); ?>
```